# What am I doing wrong with this QuickSort?

Tags: sorting, quicksort

I wrote the following QuickSort algorithm using Hoare's approach:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hoares-vs-lomuto-partition-scheme-quicksort/

```
public void Sort(int[] costs, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end)
        return;
    int splitPoint = Partition(costs, start, end);
    Console.WriteLine($"{start},{end} - Split at {splitPoint}");
    Sort(costs, start, splitPoint);
    Sort(costs, splitPoint + 1, end);
}

public int Partition(int[] costs, int start, int end) {
    Console.WriteLine($"Partitioning with {start} and {end}");
    int pivot = costs[start + (end - start) / 2];
    
    while (start < end) {
        while (start < end && costs[start] < pivot) {
            start++;
        }
        
        while (start < end && costs[end] >= pivot) {
            end--;
        }
        
        if (start < end) {
            Swap(costs, start, end);
            start++;
            end--;
        }
        
    }
    return end;
}

public void Swap(int[] costs, int a, int b) {
    Console.WriteLine($" Swapping indices {a}&{b}");
    int tmp = costs[a];
    costs[a] = costs[b];
    costs[b] = tmp;
}
```

I've spent several hours on it and I can't for the life of me figure out why it's wrong.

The test case
[3,2,1,5,6,4]
sorts to
[3,2,1,4,6,5]

I've compared it to a bunch of algorithms I've found online, and while I can figure it out with the exact Hoare approach (ie. use a do-while instead of a while) I don't understand where this code is wrong and how I can fix it.

Comment: `while (start < end && costs[end] >= pivot) {` should be `while (start < end && costs[end] > pivot) {`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError That gives me `1,2,3,4,6,5`

Comment: Post another question if you can't fix it.